# Multibib bibliographies as subsections

Tags: bibtex, subdividing, multibib

The reason why I need this modification is that I want to have a general 'Bibliography' section in which all the bibliographies created with `multibib` are included. At the moment my code (narrowed down to a minimal working example) looks like this:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @BOOK{Doe2013,
  title = {The concept of anonymity},
  author = {Doe, John},
  publisher = {Void},
  year = {2013}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{ads}{Advertisments}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\nocite{Doe2013}
\nociteads{Doe2014}
\clearpage
\section*{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyleads{plain}
\bibliographyads{ads}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Books and Articles}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

This (obviously) will create three sections in the end, which is not what I intended for I wish to have one section ("References") with two subsections ("Advertisements" and "Books and Articles"). How can I obtain that the `\bibliography`'ish macros call `\subsection*` instead of `\section*`?

### Addendum

Here is a sample `ads.bib`:

```
@BOOK{Doe2014,
  title = {The concept of anonymity 2},
  author = {Doe, John},
  publisher = {Void},
  year = {2014}
  }
```

### Edit

I forgot to mention that I want the bibliographies both automatically added to the TOC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your example preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ifdefined\chapter
  \newcommand{\refname}{References}
  \patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*{\bibname}}{%
    \section*{\refname}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}
    }{}{}
  \newcommand{\bibliographies}{%
    \chapter*{\bibname}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
  }
\else
  \newcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}
  \patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{%
    \subsection*{\refname}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\refname}
    }{}{}
  \newcommand{\bibliographies}{%
    \section*{\bibname}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}
  }
\fi
```

and `\bibliographies` (which is defined in my code snippet) right before the bibliographies start.

As you can see I expanded the functionality to classes with `\chapter`s.

### Edit

You can't use the above solution with `natbib` because it redefines the `thebibliography` environment so that the `etoolbox` patch won't be able to find what he is looking for. This code should do the job:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}
\providecommand{\refname}{References}
\@ifpackageloaded{natbib}
  {\renewcommand{\bibsection}{%
    \@ifundefined{chapter}
    {\subsection*{\refname \markboth{\refname}{\bibname}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\refname}}
    }
    {\section*{\refname \markboth{\refname}{\bibname}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}}
    }
  }}
  {\@ifundefined{chapter}
    {\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{%
      \subsection*{\refname}
      \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\refname}
      }{}{}
    }
    {\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*{\bibname}}{%
      \section*{\refname}
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}
      }{}{}
    }
  }
\@ifundefined{chapter}
  {\newcommand{\bibliographies}{%
  \section*{\bibname}
  \if@FMB@addtotoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}\fi}}
  {\newcommand{\bibliographies}{%
  \chapter*{\bibname}
  \if@FMB@addtotoc\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}\fi}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Little additional request: What if I want to use this with `natbib`? (LaTeX yields some error messages if I add it...)

Answer (score 4):

Here an alternativ suggestion:

load the package `tocbibind` and redefine section local:

```
\bgroup
\let\section\subsection
\bibliographystyleads{plain}
\bibliographyads{ads}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Books and Articles}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\egroup
```

Here the complete code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: bibtex: {  files:[ads.aux] }
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @BOOK{Doe2013,
  title = {The concept of anonymity},
  author = {Doe, John},
  publisher = {Void},
  year = {2013}
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{ads.bib}
@BOOK{Doe2014,
  title = {The concept of anonymity 2},
  author = {Doe, John},
  publisher = {Void},
  year = {2014}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{ads}{Advertisments}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\nocite{Doe2013}
\nociteads{Doe2014}
\clearpage
\section*{Bibliography}
\bgroup
\let\section\subsection
\bibliographystyleads{plain}
\bibliographyads{ads}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Books and Articles}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\let\section\subsection` alone did the trick for me