# Make a multibib bibliography a subsection rather than a section

Tags: bibtex, sectioning, subdividing, multibib

This question is similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146439/multibib-bibliographies-as-subsections) though I can't figure out how to modify the code to suit my purpose. I have the following:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Doe2013,
    title = {Title I},
    author = {Doe, John},
    publisher = {Void},
    year = {2013}
  }
@book{Doe2014,
    title = {Title II},
    author = {Doe, John},
    publisher = {Void},
    year = {2014}
  }
@book{Doe2015,
    title = {Title III},
    author = {Doe, John},
    publisher = {Void},
    year = {2015}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{ll}{Subsection of A}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks = true,
        linkbordercolor = {white},
    allcolors=cyan
}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{%
  \chapter*{\bibname}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}}{%
  \section{References}}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage[authoryear,sort,round]{natbib}
\renewcommand\refname{Bibliography}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{\bibname}}

\begin{document}
\section{PART A}
A reference to \citell{Doe2013} and \citepll{Doe2014}, and another to \citep{Doe2015}.

\bibliographystylell{plainnat}
\bibliographyll{BibProb}

\section{PART B}
Same reference to \citell{Doe2013}, but also to \cite{Doe2015}.

\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{BibProb}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:
[image: example]

I would like to have the first bibliography "2 Subsection of A" numbered as 1.1, that is, as a subsection of "1 PART A."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current code defines the bibliography to be a section (`\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{\bibname}}`).  What you have to do is to change the definition to create a subsection i.e. before part 1 (i.e., 
`\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsection{\bibname}}`) and then change the definition to section after part A, but before part B. So, what you need is something like:

```
\begin{document}
\section{PART A}
A reference to \citell{Doe2013} and \citepll{Doe2014}, and another to \citep{Doe2015}.

\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsection{\bibname}}
\bibliographystylell{plainnat}
\bibliographyll{BibProb}

\section{PART B}
Same reference to \citell{Doe2013}, but also to \cite{Doe2015}.

\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{\bibname}}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{BibProb}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That makes sense and works nicely, thanks for the explanation. As a follow up, how could I make the entries in the first bibliography (1.1 Subsection of A) appear as an enumerated list? I mean something like 1. John Doe. Title I. . . . etc.,

Comment: I guess something like \makeatletter\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}\makeatother, though the enumeration is pushed into the margin and does not shift the entire entry to the right.