# Enumerated multibib bibliography

Tags: bibtex, enumerate, natbib, multibib

I have a follow-up question to this one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472312/make-a-multibib-bibliography-a-subsection-rather-than-a-section) I posted. In the following example I have split a bibliography using multibib, for which the first bibliography is enumerated:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Doe2013,
    title = {Title I},
    author = {Doe, John},
    publisher = {Void},
    year = {2013}
  }
@book{Doe2014,
    title = {Title II},
    author = {Doe, John},
    publisher = {Void},
    year = {2014}
  }
@book{Doe2015,
    title = {Title III},
    author = {Doe, John},
    publisher = {Void},
    year = {2015}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{ll}{Subsection of A}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks = true,
        linkbordercolor = {white},
    allcolors=cyan
}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{%
  \chapter*{\bibname}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}}{%
  \section{References}}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage[authoryear,sort,round]{natbib}
\renewcommand\refname{Bibliography}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\section{PART A}
A reference to \citell{Doe2013} and \citepll{Doe2014}, and another to \citep{Doe2015}.

\makeatletter\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}\makeatother%
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsection{\bibname}}
\bibliographystylell{plainnat}
\bibliographyll{BibProb}

\section{PART B}
Same reference to \citell{Doe2013}, but also to \cite{Doe2015}.

\makeatletter\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\hfill}\makeatother%
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{\bibname}}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{BibProb}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: output]

I used the following in the first bibliography to enumerate it:

```
\makeatletter\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}\makeatother
```

though the actual numbering sits in the margin. How can I make it flush left and aligned with the section and subsection numbering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, there is an alternative with Biblatex and the category notcategory approach of separating bibliographies. In the following solution I also make use of sorting the year in reverse chronological order (option "sorting=ydnts"):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Doe2013,
    title = {Title I},
    author = {Doe, John},
    publisher = {Void},
    year = {2013}
  }
@book{Doe2014,
    title = {Title II},
    author = {Doe, John},
    publisher = {Void},
    year = {2014}
  }
@book{Doe2015,
    title = {Title III},
    author = {Doe, John},
    publisher = {Void},
    year = {2015}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks = true,
        linkbordercolor = {white},
    allcolors=cyan
}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[natbib,style=authoryear,backend=bibtex,sorting=ydnt,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{BibProb.bib}
    \DeclareBibliographyCategory{SubBib}
    \defbibenvironment{sub}
        {\begin{enumerate}}
        {\end{enumerate}}
        {\item}


\usepackage{xparse}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\section{PART A}
A reference to \citep{Doe2013}\addtocategory{SubBib}{Doe2013} and \citep{Doe2014}\addtocategory{SubBib}{Doe2014}, and another to \citep{Doe2015}.

\printbibliography[title=Subsection of A,env=sub,category=SubBib,heading=subbibnumbered]


\section{PART B}
Same reference to \citet{Doe2013}, but also to \citet{Doe2015}. 

\printbibliography[notcategory=SubBib,title=Bibliography,heading=bibnumbered]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]